# How to properly catch PHP exceptions (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some code that makes db calls and network requests and I have it wrapped in a try/catch. The problem is that I can never catch the exceptions, and they don't appear to be fatal exceptions:

```
try {
   // make db requests and network calls
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

Namely, I encounter exceptions such as these:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] 
[PDOException]
[InvalidArgumentException]
```

Is there a way to catch these exceptions? Do I need to be explicit for each possible type of exception object (meaning I must create many try/catches), or is there a recommended way of catching non fatal exceptions?

Comment: Where did you put that try/catch clause?

Comment: Is this Laravel 4.2 or 5+?

Comment: 5.1. Silly me, I didn't use a backslash before the Exception class. Let me try that...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you're using your namespaces properly, by including the Exception class at the top of your controller like this:

```
 Use Exception;
```

If you use a class without providing its namespace, PHP looks for the class in the current namespace. **Exception** class exists in global namespace, so if you do that try/catch in some namespaced code, e.g. your controller or model, you'll need to do:

```
try {
  //code causing exception to be thrown
} catch(Exception $e) {
  //exception handling
}
```

If you do it like this there is no way to miss any exceptions.

Otherwise if you get an exception in a controller code that is stored in **App\Http\Controllers**, your catch will wait for **App\Http\Controllers\Exception** object to be thrown.

Comment: Ah. Looks like a careless error on my part. I will try this and if it works I will choose this answer.

Comment: I've intentionally tried Apps\MyModel to find a record, it's throwing class "Apps\MyModel" not found exception. I tried the both FatalErrorException and \Exception, both failed. any idea?