# Unable to catch exceptions in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Unable to *catch exception* in [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) *v5.1*.

```
$companyID = $userprofile->company_id;                      
try {                       
    $companies = Company::find($companyID)->first()->name;                   
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){
    dd($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more descriptive in your question, don't just throw some code and the error message. We need to hear the description of your situation and an actual *question*.

Comment: Are you sure a `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` is the exception that's actually being thrown?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why aren't you using `Company::findOrFail($companyID)->name` and catching `ModelNotFoundException`?

Comment: Not  100 % guranted because I am figuring out the exception. Will you suggest any Parent Exception class which can catch all exceptions?

Comment: @ShubhamJolly All exceptions extend from the Exception class; you can just catch that and it'll be handled. That being said, you've got the right idea of being specific in what exceptions you catch (because then you can handle them in different ways)

Comment: You can get idea from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508223/how-to-properly-catch-php-exceptions-laravel-5-1

Comment: @ShubhamJolly To debug, catch `\Exception` - which will be matched by *any* exception - and then in your `catch {}` do `dd(get_class($ex))` to see what class it is.