# How to catch SQL Exception in Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hay I'm creating a code like this :

```
\Log::info("saving log....");
    try{
        $data = AstronautCandidateLog::insert($request->logs);
    }catch (SQLException $e)
    {
        \Log::info("SQL Exception happened");
    }catch (Exception $e)
    {
        \Log::info("Exception happened");
    }

    \Log::info("status save data : ". $data);
```

But it seems that my Exception never get hit. So how to capture exception in laravel when something wrong in sql query...??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try catching `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException`

Comment: Still no luck @canVural....

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
try { 
 //Your code
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
  dd($ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

OR

```
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

 try { 
     //Your code
    } catch(QueryException $ex){ 
      dd($ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: At last i will suggest you to refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508223/how-to-properly-catch-php-exceptions-laravel-5-1] and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679996/how-do-i-catch-a-query-exception-in-laravel-to-see-if-it-fails]. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 6):

My case: add \ before Exception class otherwise it not handle

```
try
{
//write your codes here
}

catch(\Exception $e) {

            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the Exception library in your controller. From there you can do:

```
try{
    Some queries . . .
}catch(Exception $e){
    return response()->json([
      'error' => 'Cannot excecute query',
    ],422);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement an exception in Laravel, simply include the Exception class, at the top of your controller as

```
Use Exception;
```

Then wrap the lines of code you wish to catch an exception on using try-catch statements

```
try
{
//write your codes here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

You can also return your errors in json format, incase you are making an Ajax request, this time, remember to include the Response class at the top of your controller

```
Use Response;
Use Exception;
```

then wrap your codes in a try-catch statement as follows

```
try
{
//write your codes here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return response()->json(array('message' =>$e->getMessage()));
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem, you can learn more on Laravel and Error handeling [here](https://vivvaa.com)